# Passing encoded data using base64_encode vs json_encode in hidden input

Tags: php, jquery, json, encoding, base64

I'm working on a project that users will create live blocks using Ajax .. so i encoded the block's elements map inside a hidden input's value then i will decode it inside the php file.

My question is .. I'm using (json_encode) then encodes the JSON output using (base64_encode) then pass this output in a hidden input value so Is that good?? for server for example??

or using (json_encode) only and leave the data readable for users would be enough?? Is that secure??

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Is what good? What does "for server for example" mean? Finally, you seem to think that base64 encoding a string makes it more secure, that is not the case.

Comment: Some servers using a lot of processes to encode strings with Base64, and others may don't support base64 encoding at all and the user must enable it from php settings

Comment: Doesn't sound like you have a reason to use base64, so don't.

Comment: @HadyShaltout `base64_encode/decode()` functions cannot be turned off. `json_encode/decode()` functions are also part of the PHP core (since 5.2.0).

Comment: I saw this question [link](http://themeforest.net/forums/thread/warning-base64_encode-has-been-disabled-for-security-reasons/158439)

Answer (score 1):

to answer to you question: NO, it's not safe.

base64_encode not improve any kind of security. If you have sensible data (passwords, emails...), you should never, ever put them on DOM. Put it on database and work with ID of the row. If you really want sensible information on DOM maybe its better use some public/private key encriptation.

Comment: No of course there's no password but just Control's ids, titles it's a huge array of controls inside the block, But i have no experience in security issues so may hacker changes this data then i might receive inappropriate data in server while retrieving it

Comment: Be sure you have a good authentication system and if possible under ssl layer (https). Note, some hacker can mess your website basically on two ways(can be more but this is the top): 1 - catch http request (if you use https this is safe) and change it; 2 - the common use of website, ie. the script that are called by ajax are not a good protection and authentication or unsafe forms, its possible change or even delete information.

Comment: Thanks for reply .. But it's not for my website it's a wordpress plugin for ordinary users